# How to open chrome 2 times via BAT file

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file

Everyday at work I open up chrome 2 times, and have 3 websites per window that I open up. Then I open up Word, a remote desktop and outlook.

To do all of this much quicker, I decided to write a bat file. A simple file that start all programs for me with 1 click.

The part with Chrome looks like this:

```
start C:\PROGRA~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe website1 website2 website3
start C:\PROGRA~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe website4 website5 website6
```

I hoped that this would open up 2 Chrome windows, and then open the right 3 websites in each window.
But it opens up 1 windows of Chrome, and opens up 6 websites in 1 window.

Anybody know how I can make it do what I want it to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the --new-window switch on the second line.

```
start C:\PROGRA~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe website1 website2 website3
start C:\PROGRA~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --new-window website4 website5 website6
```